# How to query all Azure Orchestration Instances to determine status for purposes of monitoring?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-durable-functions

We are using Azure Functions and the Durable Framework where we "publish" millions files (e.g. to blob storage). We have a "Starter" Function App that calls an Orchestrator to publish a single file.

Given the volume of files we are publishing, and given that there could be failures, what we'd like to do is create a monitoring / reporting / cleanup application that finds all Orchestration instances that are pending or did not complete successfully.

How do I do this?

It seems all the durable framework api's require us to know the instance id.

Manually, I use Storage Explorer to view the Function App's Table Storage and look at the task hub "instance" table and look at the "RuntimeStatus" field.

How can I do this programmatically? 
Is there an API to query? Or do I have to write my own code to read the task hub's table storage?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the [Get All Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#get-all-instances-status) HTTP API while providing the runtimeStatus query string parameter.
2. Use the [GetStatus methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#query-instances-with-filters) for .NET or JS with the parameters that don't specify an instance id and provide query filters.